# Python - Find a number and then copy it from a string

Tags: python, arrays, string

So I have a string for example `"abdc54sgh"` and I need to copy just the 54 from the string. The thing is that what goes before the number might vary. e.j. the string could be either `"hjsd23jsy"` or `"abvt12hbsy"` or any other. So I just need to copy the number which in the first one would be 23 and in the second one 12 and assign it to a variable.

Comment: So you need to skip over and non-digits and just take the digits that follow?  Or replace the non-digits with empty strings, so only the digits remain?

Comment: Exactly skip the characters and only take the digits

Comment: Do you know how to check a character to see if it is a digit or not?  Do you know how to get each of the characters in a string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using regular expressions:

```
import re
s = "abdc54sgh"
pattern = re.compile("\d+")
pattern.findall(s)
```

Or a list comprehension and `isdigit()`:

```
s = "abdc54sgh"
int("".join([x for x in s if x.isdigit()]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
def takeInt(st):
    return int("".join([ch for ch in st if not ch.isalpha()]))
```

---

```
>>> takeInt("hjsd23jsy")
23
>>> takeInt("abvt12hbsy")
12
>>>
```